# How to reduce execution time of the while-loop after substitution of the ++ operator in swift?

Tags: swift, while-loop, increment

New Xcode (7.3) is warning that the incremental operator ++ is going to be removed in next swift3. I had while loop with ++ (see below). After I have removed the incremental operator ++ , this loop is three time slower than with ++. What is the better way to change this while loop ?

Before

```
 var first = string1.startIndex
 var last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex)
 var myarray = [String]()

 while last != string1.endIndex
 {
     myarray.append(string1[first++...last++])
 }
```

After

```
 var first = string1.startIndex
 var last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex)
 var myarray = [String]()

 while last != string1.endIndex
 {
    myarray.append(string1[first...last])

    first = first.advancedBy(1) // or first = first.successor()
    last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex) // or  last = last.successor()

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you also see the performance decrease when you use `last = last.successor()` instead of `last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex)`? The former should be much faster for large values of `n`.

Comment: @ Ole Begemann Yes, I have tested it by using  -  let date_start = NSDate()  - code to execute - print("\(-date_start.timeIntervalSinceNow)").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using pre-allocation and random access assignments, rather than repeatedly appending elements to your array

The addition of the lines `first = ...` and `last = ...` should not affect performance as much as repeatedly *appending* elements (and thus repeatedly expanding your array) to an array that has not been pre-allocated. You should be able to reduce the overhead if you initialize your array `myarray` and use random access (`myarray[i]`) to assign the sliding-window string values, rather than using `.append(...)`.

```
var first = string1.startIndex
var last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex)
var myarray = [String](count: string1.characters.count-n,
                       repeatedValue: "")

for i in 0..<myarray.count {
    myarray[i] = string1[first...last]

    first = first.advancedBy(1)
    last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex)
}
```

### Benchmark

I've used the following sample `string1` and `n` to benchmark the modified solution above against your own solution:

```
var string1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pretium diam at arcu suscipit, sed molestie mi rhoncus. Donec neque sapien, luctus ultricies ex sed, tristique auctor sem. Praesent varius ullamcorper nisi a commodo. Mauris eu rutrum enim, sit amet hendrerit velit. Curabitur iaculis neque ut tellus pretium, at convallis odio posuere. Integer ultricies diam ex, sit amet faucibus odio ultrices eu. Morbi tincidunt felis tellus, eget gravida est suscipit quis. Nam nunc ipsum, molestie sit amet neque at, aliquam maximus lacus. Sed bibendum massa a lorem eleifend, non eleifend felis commodo. Vivamus eget sem luctus, aliquam dolor nec, finibus diam. Morbi id justo vehicula, eleifend arcu nec, hendrerit neque. Donec ex ante, fringilla id rhoncus nec, porta id tortor. Donec dapibus nisl nibh, non posuere lacus egestas non. Duis massa quam, elementum sit amet volutpat eget, tincidunt sodales urna. Donec at congue ligula, a sollicitudin tortor."
string1 = string1+string1+string1 // 2880 characters
let n = 4
```

Results of benchmark (measured using [this `QuartzCore`-based function](https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/4201fbe86473f6edb207))

- Pre-initialized array solution with `for i in ...` loop: **2.5s**
- `.append(..)` solution with `while` loop, as presented in your question: **32.5s**

If execution time is of importance, clearly you'd benefit by pre-initializing the array and using random access assignments rather than repeatedly using `.append(..)`.

---

Finally, you could ask yourself if you really need to explicitly store all the substrings from the sliding-window, or if it suffices to store the ranges corresponding to them. If `n` is large, `myarray` above will contain large amount of duplicate characters/overlapping substrings. In such a case, you might be better off just saving an array of `Range<String.CharacterView.Index>` elements, which can readily be used to extract the relevant substring of `string1` on the fly. E.g.:

```
var first = string1.startIndex
var last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex)
var rangeArr = [Range<String.CharacterView.Index>](
        count: string1.characters.count-n,
        repeatedValue: first...last)

for i in 0..<rangeArr.count {
    rangeArr[i] = first...last

    first = first.advancedBy(1)
    last = first.advancedBy(n, limit: string1.endIndex)
}
```

Comment: Great, it is very useful advice for me! I have started to write the code for bioinformatics, to work with large sequences.

Comment: @VYT Happy to help. I'll add an additional remark regarding actually storing all the substrings explicitly.

Comment: To store the ranges instead of strings is another great idea, it will be  useful especially for whole genome analysis. It is nice to learn good things. Thanks!

Comment: @VYT I'll wrap up and mention that curiously enough, ranges over a string is actually larger (80bytes) than the strings themselves (24bytes), (see `sizeof(String)` vs. `sizeof(Range<String.CharacterView.Index>)`), so depending on if also memory is limited, perhaps actually storing the strings is to prefer (even if storing ranges possibly feels "neater"). Good luck with your project!

Comment: @VYT Finally, off-topic w.r.t. the question, but w.r.t. your comment on genomes: if this Q&A covers storing sequences of genomes, perhaps using strings (24bytes per string) is overkill: since the genomes can only take letters `A, C, G, T`, you could actually store any such 4-letter combination within a single (unsigned) byte: the letters form a base-4, and base-4 of "4 positions" is neatly 256, i.e., the number of representable different states of one single byte (2^8). You could use a dict. to re-transform these 0->255 states to the corr. letter combinations. Again, however, a bit off-topic:)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification !

Answer (score 2):

Change incrementation from `first++` to `first += 1` – *it's about principles over deprecated version*

But if make deep search, you can find that `increment` over `String.CharacterView.Index` is implemented custom postfix operator, where accepts generic with `_Incrementable` protocol, which has declared `successor` method for return next chain value. 
Why is `++` faster over direct `successor` – who knows, apparently some optimisations is under development, and in **Swift 3** will have better speed.

Comment: If am using first += 1 instead of first.advancedBy(1) it is not working as  += is not applied to Index.

Comment: hmm, so, just time to wait improvements ... maybe yes maybe not, not a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a for loop instead of a while and then access directly using the index.

```
var myarray = [String]()
for var i in string1.startIndex ... string1.endIndex {
    myarray.append(string1[i])
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: forget `for var i; i<j; j++`, use `for .. in` instead

Comment: haha. Moving from one deprecated solution to another deprecated solution :)

Comment: Yeah good point it should be a for in loop to remain swift like.  Will edit my code

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't put the incrementing on a separate line?

```
while last != string1.endIndex
 {
     first += 1
     last += 1
     myarray.append(string1[first...last])
 }
```

Comment: The first += 1 and  last += 1 are not applied to Index